# trigger android hardware event from a service

Tags: android, events, android-service

Is it possible to trigger a hardware event from a service? At the very least, I'm hoping to emulate trackball movements and clicking events such that an active app will process them normally.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don' think so and certainly hope not. That would be a serious security issue.

If you are just testing with JUnit etc then this is possible with the instrumentation classes.